# Question about chords within a musical key

Tags: guitar

Why does an F sharp major chord work when playing in A major chord?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Do you mean why does an F sharp major chord sound acceptable when used in the key of A major?

Comment: OP could mean A major key?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Seems very likely, probably best to wait for clarification.

Comment: Or, do you mean why does an F#major chord work over an A major chord - which is what my answer is about. If not, my answer's wrong!

Comment: @Tim I'd be surprised if OP really was asking about polychords, since most of our new users' first posts tend toward the beginner side of music theory, but it's a great answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question as it's asked: A contains A C♯ and E. F♯  contains F♯ A♯ andC♯. That makes one common note - C♯.

So, from an F♯ view, we have the standard F♯ major triad. Over this, there's an E note, making F♯7 (dominant 7). That just leaves the A note, which could be described as the ♯9 in F♯.But actually is Gx.

All this gives us what has become known as the Hendrix chord:**F♯7♯9**. Also found in the Beatles 'Taxman', the Batman theme (Neil Hefti, I think), and a Glenn Miller number from the '40s, so not that modern.

Be very careful with voicings of the 7♯9 chord. A few do not sound good at all.

Comment: Well played Sir!

Comment: @replete - got there - and the last edit is a piece de resistance!

Comment: @Tim "If there's one thing I've learned from the internet, it's to never assume that someone's a girl based off of an anime girl profile picture" *-A (catfished) commenter on Reddit*